# Translations for Vamadeva Samhita & Kapila Samhita required

Tags: scripture, translation-request

Can anyone please direct me to the links for english translations of Vamadeva Samhita and Kapila Samhita along with the original Sanskrit verses.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  Are you referring to the texts called "Vamadeva Samhita" and "Kapila Samhita" which contain the story of Puri Jagannath?  Or are you referring to some unrelated texts which have those names?

Comment: That's right Keshav. Vamadeva Samhita has the rituals and Kapila samhita about the geography & related stories of Puri Jagannath

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan aren't these Pancharatra texts which require initiation?

Comment: @Yogi Yeah, I think they are Pancharatra Agamas.

Comment: Just curious if Kapila Samhita and Kapila Purana (upa or shala purana may be) are same or totally different.

Comment: Any update please